# My cat is prescribed animax ointment today. Is it safe to ingest?

Tags: cats

My cat has a bold patch below neck and I took him to a vet yesterday. We were prescribed animax ointment.
I researched a lot and it says avoid licking in 20-30 mins until it’s dried.
To be more safer, I put him on cone for 4 hours already and I think it’s dried.
Is it safe for cat to lick after it’s dried? I mean even if it’s dried, a medication residue should be remained.

*Update*
My vet says a cone is not necessary once it is dried.
She said to use a small amount for fast dry.

Comment: For a fast solution please call your vet! And post it here. It can take some time until someone experienced comes to answer.

Comment: Was there a leaflet (long sheet of paper) in the package of the ointment? Usually you'll find all information you need on the leaflet. If it says to avoid licking for 30 minutes, then it's safe to ingest after it's dried. If the leaflet says to avoid licking without a time constraint, the it's not safe to ingest after drying. You can [edit] your question to add information from the leaflet if you have difficulty interpreting it.